# problems with a messagecontract and tcp binding

Tags: wcf, tcp, message

I have a wcf service, it is async and use the net tcp binding. Until now, it works fine. I can get the metadata, generate the proxy class for the clients... etc.

However,, I need to define a message contract because I need to send files to the service from the client. This class is in a common library, where also I have the STEs (self tracking entities).

Also I add the new async method in the service that let me send files.

My message contract is the following:

```
[MessageContract]
public class FileDataStream : IDisposable
{
    //[MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    //[MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public System.IO.Stream DataStream {get; set;}
}
```

If I use this class, when I try to get the metadata in the same way that I follow in the past, now in the internet explorer says me that the page can't be found. The client can't connect. And If I use netstat -ona | find "7997" I get nothing, so the service is not running correctly.

However, if in my message contract class I delete the messagecontract attribute, the all works fine. When I mean that all works fine is because the service is running correctly.

However, the binary information of the file does not arrive correctly to the service. In the examples that I read about the transfer of files in WCF, I always see that a message contract is used, because to send more information, like as the name of the file, the message contract is needed.

So I would like to know what I am doing wrong. In other situations, when I can't get the metadata, is because I don't have the binding correctly set, but I don't know if I need an special configuration when I want to use a message contract.

My service cofiguration is the following:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>


      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceDocumentos" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                       transferMode="Streamed" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                       openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                       sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxConnections="100">
          <security mode="None"/>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>

        <binding name="ServiceCore" maxBufferSize="67108864"
                      maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" maxBufferPoolSize="67108864"
                       transferMode="Buffered" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                       openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                       sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxConnections="100">
          <security mode="None"/>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="67108864" maxBytesPerRead="67108864" maxStringContentLength="67108864"/>
          <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>      
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CMMSService" name="GTS.CMMS.Service.Service">

        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceDocumentos"
                 name="ServiceDocumentos" contract="GTS.CMMS.Service.IServiceDocumentos"
         address="ServiceDocumentos/">
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address ="ServiceCore/"
                 binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceCore"
                 name="ServiceCore" contract="GTS.CMMS.Service.IService">
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"
                 listenUriMode="Explicit">
        </endpoint>

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7997/CMMSService" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:7998/CMMSService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>


      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CMMSService">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />

          <serviceThrottling
                    maxConcurrentCalls="64"
                    maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647"
                    maxConcurrentSessions="50"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does the tracing log says?

Comment: The tracing log is the exception or is it something different? How can I get the tracing log? Thanks.